# With XML, when does jquery's .attr() and getAttribute() return different results?

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, tinymce

I'm getting an XML response from a server and parsing it in jquery (jQuery 1.8.2 on Chrome 23.0.1271.64 and Firefox 15.01) to get various attributes.  2 out of 3 times it works as planned, but that third time, the attr() call returns the entire element instead of the attr value.

As an example:

```
$(xmlData).find("template").attr("largeBlockFirst")
```

returns an array of nodes with one entry with a tagName of template, while

```
$(xmlData).find("template").get(0).getAttribute("largeBlockFirst")
```

returns a string.

My theory is that for some reason there is something different in the xmlData that I can't see just by serializing it.  In each case, my method is called by a success callback on an ajax call.  Each response is of content type text/xml (always the same url, but just in case I checked the type every time).

Any ideas what might cause the xml to be parsed differently?

Comment: Can you create an example on jsfiddle.net (using a string of xml I suppose)

Comment: I'm not sure I can.  The problem is the same code responds differently and I can't determine what is different about the environment it is functioning in (arguments or context).  Do you know of any cases where those two return such different answers?

Comment: no, as far as I understand `.attr()` should always return a string regardless.

Comment: Well I have new info, but it's really strange.  The difference between the situations is that in one case I had opened a tinymce editor, extracted it's data and closed it.  That data has nothing to do with data I'm retrieving from the server, but for some reason when I call .attr("x") it's calling tinyMCE's attr function.  It almost sounds like some kind of namespace pollution..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: http://brian.pontarelli.com/2007/09/12/how-to-get-jquery-and-tinymce-to-work/

Instead of using `$` you may want to use `jQuery`, and possibly call `jQuery.noConflict`

Comment: I haven't tried it, but that would be weird, I've never had any trouble with that before.  I'm using the tinymce jquery version.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that tinymce before 3.5.4 breaks jquery's of 1.7.2 or newer versions.  One of the ways is that it breaks the attr function.  I upgraded to the newest tinymce and it works fine now.  Hopefully there isn't anything for me to worry about from the tinymce upgrade, crosses fingers.